# What are the best environments for typing equations and texts on the same line?

Tags: equations, align

I've traditionally just used

```
\begin{align}
  y = x \ \ \ \ \ \text{description of eqn} \\
  y = z + 2 \ \ \ \ \text{description of second equation}
\end{align}
```

But, I'm not sure if this is the best option available for things like this. Are there other environment more suitable for what I'm trying to accomplish? Sometimes, the description I'm typing doesn't fit on one line, and it's a bit difficult to get that to work with the align environment.

Comment: Without a `&`, it's really just a `gather` environment.  There are many other horizontal spacing commands that would be better than several `\ ` in a row.  But I would consider `y&=x&\text{blah}`, possibly in a `flalign`.  And "best" does not work well on Stack sites, as there's not an objective way to answer your question.

Comment: `align` should always have `&` otherwise there is no alignment.

Comment: It not really like gather: The equations are  actually aligned by their ends.